# Change theme in production

Tags: wordpress

I plan to change the design of my site. My site has a lot of visitors, so I can't do it right in production because it takes quite a lot time to adjust some settings, make some pages etc.

If I copy my production to localhost and do these adjustments I'll change database (for example I need to create a menu, some new pages). At the same time in production some posts will be added, and maybe something else will change in database.

How to deal with this situation? Basically I want to have all my things done on localhost and then push it to production but how to synchronize these things?

Answer (score 0):

What I do, and I find works best for my needs, is set up a testing-only blog with the current theme you are using, and a few posts with media.  Make the changes to the theme and work out any issues.  Then just push the changes to the production server and you shouldn't have any issues.  I didn't bother copying my database to my local server, and didn't need to.

Comment: Hmm... not in my case. For example I know that in my current theme a lot of posts don't have thumbnails, or don't have menu at all. I used a lot of static HTML. So if I just push new theme I'll get what I recently got on localhost: no main page (because I need to construct it wish page builder - theme feature), wrong images (or no images at all), no menu etc...